# Javascript, module.exports in CommonJS modules

Tags: javascript, module, require, commonjs

In Eloquent Javascript (http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html) there's this explanation and implementation of require():

> ...problem is that it is not possible for a module to directly export
>   a value other than the exports object, such as a function. For
>   example, a module might want to export only the constructor of the
>   object type it defines. Right now, it cannot do that because require
>   always uses the exports object it creates as the exported value.
>
> The traditional solution for this is to provide modules with another
>   variable, module, which is an object that has a property exports. This
>   property initially points at the empty object created by require but
>   can be overwritten with another value in order to export something
>   else.

```
function require(name) {
  if (name in require.cache)
    return require.cache[name];

  var code = new Function("exports, module", readFile(name));
  var exports = {}, module = {exports: exports};
  code(exports, module);

  require.cache[name] = module.exports;
  return module.exports;
}
require.cache = Object.create(null);
```

So, can someone explain, how module.exports is a solution? Why can't i just overwrite exports?

Comment: Because `exports` is just a local variable that has no significance whatsoever outside of the module code?

Comment: (Of course, they *could* have used the `return` value of the module "function" instead)

Comment: @Bergi so... just like module.exports (which is too local variable that has no significance outside of the module code)?

Comment: No, *that* is a **property** of the `module` object, which is an object that is passed in from outside.

Comment: "code(exports, module)"
Just as exports.

Comment: That's not what we're talking about. "*The solution for this is to provide another variable, `module`, which is an object*"!

Comment: Sorry, i just don't get it. Exports and module are objects, that are defined inside require(). Module object has property exports, which points (references?) at the same object as exports. Inside modules (files i mean), we change exports object (to which module.exports points), and then return module.exports. Why not just return exports? Why it can't be a function? I don't get why module object is needed.

Comment: You can mutate objects (add/change) properties, but when you assign to variables that stays local.

Comment: But code returns exports (module.exports) value. So, no matter what exports is (function, number), it wil return what needed. Isn't that right? Why when "exports = function(){...}" i need "return module.exports", and not "return exports"

Comment: Because when you assign to `module.exports`, you change the property. When you assign to `exports`, you only change the local variable, **and not the `exports` variable inside `require`**. That's why it uses `return module.exports` instead of `return exports` - they might **not be the same** after evaluating `code`!

Comment: Whoa! Thank you! I think i got part about exports!
So, it's like, at start of code(exports, module), code_exports exports variable inside code) points to the same empty object as require_exports (exports inside require), so we can add properities and stuff to that. But when doing assignment, for example code_exports = function(){}, it doesn't do anything, because require() will return require_exports. 
Whoa, at this point i think i got part about module.exports too! So, if we assign function inside the code to that, require() will return this function! 
Thank you for your patience!

Comment: And just small question: why having exports object in that case at all? Just as shortcut for module.exports, when you need to export object?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it's just a shortcut, for the usual case of doing `exports.a = function() {…};  exports.b = function() {…}`

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I really apeciate your help.